# Add column to pivottable VBA excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013, vba

I need to add a column to a pivottable in, whose content does not change, using VBA in Excel 2013.

How can I add a column, that is not a calculated field?

Comment: If the column is not part of the source data, then it *is* a calculated field or item.

Comment: Sorry, I am maybe a bit unclear.. I want nothing calculated in the column, just simply add comments in the cells.

Comment: You'd have to add them to the source data if you need them to be an actual part of the pivot table. Otherwise add them alongside.